# Wordpress Gutenberg Block, creating Aside element

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

Is it possible to create a Plugin for Gutenberg Block, when you click on it, opens a  or , but using JS just  for Backend, for Front just HTML, cause its headless. I tried many ways but did not succeed.

```
`Is there a wp.element that is not static like this one and just provides text in front? 

  edit: function () {
    return wp.element.createElement("h3", null, "Hello, this is from the admin editor screen.")
  },
  save: function () {
    return wp.element.createElement("h1", null, "This is the frontend.")
  }
})`
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a custom block that renders dynamically on the frontend - or are you using WordPress completely headless? The example code given is very generic, can you elaborate more?

Comment: Thank you for answer. I'm using completly headless. Fronted is in React. 
[link](https://codepen.io/Helloworldx2/pen/gOdJQNe?editors=1010) @S.Walsh